# Is there API for uber ola such cab services

Tags: java

Is there API available for taxi services like ola, uber etc? If yes can you people please share links? I want to create aggregator application

Answer (score 0):

There is one for Uber: https://developer.uber.com/. However, the [Terms of Use](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/terms-of-use) prohibit you to aggregate data.